# C++17 atomics and condition_variable deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, c++17, condition-variable

I have the following code, which deadlocks on the commented lines. Basically f1 and f2 run as individual threads in the program. f1 expects i to be 1 and decrements it, notifying the cv. f2 expects i to be 0 and increments it, notifying the cv. I assume the deadlock occurs if f2 increments i to 1, calls cv.notify(), then f1 reads a stale value of i (which is 0) because there is no memory synchronization between the mutex and i and then waits and never gets woken up. Then f2 also enters a sleep state and now both threads are waiting on a cv that will never be notified.

How can I write this code so that the deadlock does not occur? Basically what I want to be able to achieve is having some atomic state that gets updated by two threads. If the state is not correct in one of the threads, I do not want to spin; rather I want to use the cv functionality (or something similar) to wake the thread up when the value is correct.

I am using g++-7 to compile the code with O3 (although the deadlock occurs in both O0 and O3).

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_size_t i{0};
std::mutex mut;
std::condition_variable cv;

void f1() {
  while (1) {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
      cv.wait(lk, []() { return i.load() > 0; }); // deadlocks
    }
    --i;
    cv.notify_one();
    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl; // Only to avoid optimization
  }
}

void f2() {
  while (1) {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
      cv.wait(lk, []() { return i.load() < 1; }); // deadlocks
    }
    ++i;
    cv.notify_one();
    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl; // Only to avoid optimization
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(f1);
  std::thread t2(f2);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: cout is only to avoid compiler optimization.

Comment: —i and ++I should be inside the while. Otherwise conditions is never reached

Comment: You print values after they could've been altered by another thread.

Comment: I'm guessing but I think a spurious wakeup may happen after one thread has changed the value but *before* it calls notify. So both threads can end up waiting on the variable without any possibility of notify being called again. Moving the increment/decrement into the lock seems to fix it.

Comment: While moving it into the while is a solution, I'm wondering if it's possible to do without double synchronization (the atomic is already synchronizing i).

Comment: @user1413793 Make `i` not atomic, then you only need to rely on the mutex for synchronization.

Comment: Why C++17? Is there anything not available in C++11?

Comment: I would recommend to rewrite `cv.wait(lk, []() { return i.load() > 0; });` into `while (i==0) cv.wait(lk);` and similarly in `f2` to make it more clear.

Comment: I believe that on linux, the use of conditionnal variable and mutex is redundant, when a mutex is released, it automaticaly awakes one waiting threads. (TBC, if not, realy and if you target linux, just directly use futex)

Comment: @Oliv, in linux, cv-s are comparable to signals, not mutexes, but cv-s require a mutex to work. I haven't worked with futexes immediately, but if it is not portable, then you're balancing portability with speed or smaller code.  Wikipedia calls condition variable a higher-level locking abstraction of futex.

Comment: @stefaanv  I can't find a wikipedia page where this is said, I would like to read this page evenif I know indeed that futex are used to implement condition variable as mutex. My opinion is that c++ mutex are a too high abstraction, of what is actualy a simple mechanism. For example, I see questions about implementing a lock that spin some time then lock a mutex, this is redundant too, this is how mutex are implemented with futex! The aim of multithreading is efficiency, but the synchronization primitive provided by the C++ standard can just lead to suboptimal constructs! So I will never use it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex first paragraph.

Comment: @Oliv What do you mean? How do you program w/o CV on linux?

Comment: @curiousguy I don't remenber what I meant. But here clearly, on linux there is no need for a cv, neither a mutex. It could be done with a compare_and_exchange loop, the futex will be an optimization to avoid the spin lock. Actualy, coding using kernel primitive is much easier and less error prone. As you are curious, I advice you to code without glibc, direct raw assembly system calls, not even start up files. The kernel/user space interface is the right level of abstraction! Posix/glibc/pthread ... that's crap, just think about errno,

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is that the value of `i` could be altered and `notify_one` could be called in the interval after another thread evaluated `return i.load() > 0;` but before lambda call returns and cv resumes wait. This way the change of atomic variable won't be observed by another thread and there is no one to wake it up to check again. This could be solved by locking mutex when changing variable though doing so would defeat the purpose of atomic.

Answer (score 4):

I think VTT's answer is correct, just want to show what can happen. First, the code can be rewritten into the following form:

```
void f1() {
   while (1) {
      {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
         while (i == 0) cv.wait(lk);
      }
      --i;
      cv.notify_one();
   }
}

void f2() {
   while (1) {
      {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
         while (i >= 1) cv.wait(lk);
      }
      ++i;
      cv.notify_one();
   }
}
```

Now, consider the following time line, `i` being `0` initially:

```
time step    f1:               f2:
=========    ================= ================
        1                      locks mut
        2                      while (i >= 1) F
        3                      unlocks mut
        4    locks mut
        5    while (i == 0) T                  
        6                      ++i;
        7                      cv.notify_one();
        8    cv.wait(lk);
        9    unlocks mut(lk) 
       10                      locks mut                   
       11                      while (i >= 1) T
       12                      cv.wait(lk);
```

Effectively, `f1` waits at the moment when `i` is `1`. Both threads are now waiting in a blocking state at once.

---

The solution would be to put modifications of `i` into locked sections. Then, `i` even does not need to be an atomic variable.

Comment: The original notation in the question of OP solves the age old confusion of using the wait function without a predicate, so in that sense, it made things clearer that you now show what predicate you actually expect and that you're not just waiting on some signal that in order to work has to be in a while-loop.  Also, optional time-outs are handled better (`cv::wait_for()`).

Comment: Also, in your scenarios, `while (i == 0)` and `cv.wait(lk);` are synced, so the thread can't be interrupted between them.

Comment: @stefaanv I updated the time line to include locking and unlocking of mutex.

Comment: Yes, that works because ++i is not guarded. And the scenario easier shown in the while notation.

Answer (score 3):

You call `cv.notify_one();` when a thread does not own the mutex. It may cause notification is sent to empty. Imagine `f2` starts before `f1`. `f2` calls `cv.notify_one();` but `f1` is not in `cv.wait` yet.

Acquired mutex guarantees that `f2` is either in `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut)` or waits for notification.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_size_t i{0};
std::mutex mut;
std::condition_variable cv;

void f1() {
  while (1) {
    std::size_t ii;
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
      cv.wait(lk, []() { return i.load() > 0; });
      ii = --i;
      cv.notify_one();
    }
    std::cout << "i = " << ii << std::endl;
  }
}

void f2() {
  while (1) {
    std::size_t ii;
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
      cv.wait(lk, []() { return i.load() < 1; });
      ii = ++i;
      cv.notify_one();
    }
    std::cout << "i = " << ii << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(f1);
  std::thread t2(f2);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

BTW `std::atomic_size_t i` could be `std::size_t i`.

Comment: I don't think you need to hold the mutex when notifying. Doesn't that run the risk of the notified thread waking up before the mutex has been unlocked?

Comment: @super According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one): "The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock."

Comment: If you want change i to `std::size_t`, then the `std::cout` statements must be guarded because they access i.

Comment: @stefaanv Thank you. I updated the answer. It is a bad idea to guard `std::cout`, therefore I added local variables.

Answer (score -3):

Since **i** is atomic, there is no need to guard its modification with the mutex.

The waits on the condition variable in **f1** and **f2** wait for ever unless a spurious wake-up occurs, because the condition variable was never notified. Since spurious wake-ups are not guaranteed, I suggest to check for the condition before waiting on the condition variable, and eventually notify the condition variable for the other thread.

There is another problem with your code. Both functions **f1** and **f2** will never end. So your **main** function will wait for ever joining its threads.

Comment: The `std::wait()` function does a `while(! pred) wait_without_pred()` internally (see answer of Daniel Langr) and not ending programs for demo purposes are normally closed with ctrl-c, the joins are needed to keep the program alive.