# Does shared variable related to condition variable really need to be modified under mutex?

Tags: c++, mutex, atomic, race-condition, condition-variable

Consider the following quote about `std::condition_variable` from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

> The `condition_variable` class is a synchronization primitive that can be used to block a thread, or multiple threads at the same time, until another thread both modifies a **shared variable** (the *condition*), and notifies the `condition_variable`.
>
> The thread that intends to modify the variable has to
>
> 1. acquire a `std::mutex` (typically via `std::lock_guard`)
> 2. **perform the modification while the lock is held**
> 3. execute `notify_one` or `notify_all` on the `std::condition_variable` (the lock does not need to be held for notification)
>
> **Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex** in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

An exemplary typical scenario of this approach is as follows:

```
// shared (e.d., global) variables:
bool proceed = false;
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
```

```
// thread #1:
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
   while (!proceed) cv.wait(l); // or, cv.wait(l, []{ return proceed; });
}
```

```
// thread #2:
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
   proceed = true;
}
cv.notify_one();
```

However, @Tim in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38185016/580083) came up with (kind-of an academic) alternative:

```
std::atomic<bool> proceed {false}; // atomic to avoid data race
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
```

```
// thread #1:
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
   while (!proceed) cv.wait(l);
}
```

```
// thread #2:
proceed = true; // not protected with mutex
{ std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m); }
cv.notify_one();
```

It obviously does not meet the requirements of the above cppreference quote since `proceed` shared variable (atomic in this case) **is not modified under the mutex**.

**The question is if this code is correct.** In my opinion, it is, since:

1. First option is that `!proceed` in `while (!proceed)` is evaluated as **false**. In that case, `cv.wait(l);` is not invoked at all.
2. Second option is that `!proceed` in `while (!proceed)` is evaluated as **true**. In that case, `cv.notify_one()` cannot happen until thread #1 enters `cv.wait(l);`.

**Am I missing something or is cppreference wrong in this regard?** (For instance, are some reordering issues involved?)

---

And, what if `proceed = true;` would be changed to `proceed.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);`?

Comment: `The question is if this code is correct.` Could you define "correct"? What should the code achieve? It should only allow one thread to proceed, right?

Comment: @KamilCuk Basically, I ask whether both shown variants have the same effect (and, cannot result in undefined behavior, abnormal program termination, race conditions, deadlocks, etc.).

Comment: I think [C++17 atomics and condition_variable deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622713/c17-atomics-and-condition-variable-deadlock/49623578#49623578) contains an example of possible trouble with mixture of atomics and condvars.

Comment: @user7860670 That is a different case, there is no mutex locked between modification of a shared variable and notification in the question you linked.

Comment: The key part is that value is not modified under locked mutex.